# Update progress dialog from outside of a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, http, progressdialog

I have a method which displays a progress dialog...and on a seperate thread I am executing 3 HTTP requests...

Here is the code...

```
public void downloadData(View v)
{
    final ProgressDialog prog;

    try
    {
        // setup progress dialog
        prog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        prog.setTitle("Downloading Data");
        prog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        prog.setIcon(R.drawable.firstdroidicon);
        prog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        prog.setCancelable(false);
        prog.show();


        Thread syncThread = new Thread();
        syncThread = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                String result = "";
                String URL = //url for ReST service
                String urlParams = "";

                GetByREST gbr = new GetByREST();

                // run the customer search
                prog.setMessage("Fetching Customers");//update progress dialog
                result = //execute first post

                // run the contact search
                prog.setMessage("Fetching Contacts");//update progress dialog
                result = //execute second post

                // run the item saved search
                prog.setMessage("Fetching Items");//update progress dialog
                result = //execute third post

                prog.dismiss();
        };
        syncThread.start();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        messageBox("downloadData", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

How can I update the progress dialog message before each request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap any calls to UI functions on the thread in runOnUIThread calls.  runOnUIThread takes a runnable and will execute it on the UI thread when available.  This gets around the restriction of only being able to update the UI on the UI thread.

Comment: I have tried this and it works fine. However this doing this for each of the requests can make the code look messy.

Comment: Easiest way to not make it look messy is to not use an annonymous class-  put the code of the runnable elsewhere and just create it via new in the thread runnable.  In fact, since all 3 are just setting different strings, you can make them 1 class that takes a string parameter.

Answer (score 1):

To update UI from background thread. You can use

1. Handler   : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html
2. AsyncTask : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

In your case you should `AsyncTask` which basically take care for Network calls in `doInBackground()` Method and update the progress dialog in `onPostExecute()` method

Comment: I don't know much about AsyncTask. Is it easy to implement?

Comment: There are lots of tutorials available. Its better to use that. Background Threading will be taken care by AsyncTask only. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write your own threading for simple network calls. You can use `AsyncTask` that can execute your network calls, and from in there you have the possibility to publish progress, which is code that can safely run on the UI thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html